# i get python function NameError

Tags: python, function, nameerror

I get `NameError` when I run this code:

> NameError: name 'word' is not defined

```
def disemvowel(word):
    vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]
    for vowel in vowels:
        if vowel in word:
            word.remove(vowle)
            print(word)

disemvowel(word)
```

Comment: You will also find that you get `'vowle' is not defined`, if you manage to run your function.

Comment: From what you have posted we can only confirm that you haven't defined word when calling your function (and that you have mispelt vowle).

Comment: You probably get the error at `disemvowel(word)` because you have no (global) var named `word`.

Comment: how i should define the "word" i dont understand that and yup the code give me NameError: name 'word' is not defined

Comment: The last line of your code is trying to execute the function `disemvowel`. To call it, you need to provide a string as an argument. For instance `disemvowel("my string")`. `disemvowel(word)` won't work unless you have already specified what string `word` represents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're getting is due to the variable `word` being uninitialized. Furthermore, I don't believe `.remove()` is a valid function on strings.

Regardless, you had a typo in this line:

```
word.remove(vowle) // should be 'vowel'
```

Try:

```
def disemvowel(word):
    vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]
    out = word

    for vowel in vowels:
        if vowel in word.lower():
            out = out.replace(vowel, "")

    print(out)

word = "orange"
disemvowel(word)
```

The above will output the following:

> rng

Answer (score -1):

there more than one way to do that but i did figure a way to do that using `.remove()`.....i did convert `word` to a `list` then i did convert back to a `string` just to understand how it works

```
word = input("enter the name: ")
new_word = list(word)


def disemvowel(word):

    for vowel in 'aeiou':
        if vowel.lower() in new_word:
            new_word.remove(vowel)

    strword = ''.join(new_word)
    print(strword)


disemvowel(word)
```

Comment: Using `lower()` on `vowel` is incorrect as you hard-define them as `'aeiou'` (already lower-case). To manage variations in case, you need to `.lower()` the value of `word` collected from the user.